# copying sockaddr_storage to another sockaddr_storage changes address

Tags: c++, copy, winsock, variable-assignment

Hey... As in a recent question (nobody did react on the last changes) I have a problem with assigning a sockaddr structure filled by `recvfrom`.

As I have been advised , I did change my sockaddr to sockaddr_storage and casted it in the last moment to be sure of having enough space for the address...

But the problem of

```
sockaddr_storage s1, s2; 
/*recv address into s1*/ 
s2 = s1;
```

or `memcpy(&s2, &s1, sizeof(sockaddr_storage));`

Do not work... anyone  has a solution to copy a sockaddr_storage or at least the address to hold it in a structure and get the original value later on?...

Thank You.

**EDIT: definitions for sockaddr and sockaddr_storage (msdn):**

```
struct sockaddr {
        ushort  sa_family;
        char    sa_data[14];
};


typedef struct sockaddr_storage {
  short   ss_family;
  char    __ss_pad1[_SS_PAD1SIZE];
  __int64 __ss_align;
  char    __ss_pad2[_SS_PAD2SIZE];
} SOCKADDR_STORAGE, *PSOCKADDR_STORAGE;
```

Comment: For those who don't know, can you provide the definition of sockaddr_storage struct/class?

Comment: Thanks. Based on the definition I expect memcpy to work. Can you tell us why you think memcpy did not work?

Comment: I first noticed it, because the client never received an answer.
Of course this could have been due to the natural bevhaviour of UDP not to be an reliable protocoll. But when I used the original address from recvfrom, it did work...

So I did set some breakpoints and read out the address manually and voila: the address changed after the copying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your copying appears to be correct (the `memcpy`, at least). I suspect you are misparsing the result. You can try using `memcmp` to verify that the copy was successful.